# How to use Doctrine Fixture to load test database for PHP unit testing?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit, phpdotenv

I am trying to set a database environment to test my Doctrine ORM Entity classes, without changing my real database.

I followed [Symfony's documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html), but when I run `php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load` I get the warning:

> Careful, database "graph" will be purged. Do you want to continue? (yes/no) [no]:

This is despite the fact that I have set an environment variable in my `.env.test` file:

> DATABASE_URL=mysql://testUser:testPassword@127.0.0.1/graph_test

Edit: here is the entire `.env.test` file:

```
# define your env variables for the test env here
KERNEL_CLASS='App\Kernel'
APP_SECRET='$ecretf0rt3st'
SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=999999
PANTHER_APP_ENV=panther

# Database test
DATABASE_URL=mysql://testUser:testPassword@127.0.0.1/graph_test
```

I tried to change my `test/bootstrap.php` file but I get the same warning.

Is there a way to tell doctrine to take the `DATABASE_URL` value from the `.env.test` file? Any help will be appreciated.

PS
There is no need for more than one test .env file.

Comment: please provide your .env.test file (strip out credentials), maybe you should use `.env.local`? when you debugging locally?

Comment: Maybe I will do that in the future, right now I conduct only local testing.

Comment: Try renaming .env.test to .env.local to ensure it's used. As symfony documentation points out if you want to use a custom (in your case "test" env) additional steps are required. `.env.local` is used by default. https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#overriding-environment-values-via-env-local

Comment: Try `php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env=test`

Comment: You first should answer, so that there's something for me to accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env=test` you will only affect your test database.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to load a config make sure it's either defined in .env.local or if you're using a custom environment like `test` add the `--env=test` parameter to your commands

```
  php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env=test
  php bin/console server:run --env=test
```

Answer (score 0):

doctrine tests include running migrations in order to have the same data in the database for each test run.

from the page you posted...

## [Resetting the Database Automatically Before each Test¶](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html#resetting-the-database-automatically-before-each-test)

This will cause the message `Careful, database ... will be purged.` This is a warning, not an error.

Comment: But I don't want my real database and my test database to be the same. I want the real database to be left intact, but to reset the **test** database before each test.